# Captions are not stick together with the figure in nature class

Tags: floats, captions

I am using nature class file. In that class, \includegraphics was not working. Which I solved with some modification in the .cls file. However, the captions and labels are not working. Could anyone suggest what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: with not knowing what you change in document class we can't help you. please provide small complete document which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I commented last two lines of the cls file :                                                                         %% ignore all \includegraphics commands in the document
%\AtBeginDocument{\let\includegraphics\NAT@ignore}

%\newcommand{\NAT@ignore}[2][]{n

Comment: More detail can found here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362195/nature-include-graphics